# Microsoft Access 2013 Conditional Parameter Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause

I have a form which uses two parameters to search/filter down available cases. There are three controls: txtCaseFiler, cboClients, and lstCases.

cboClients shows a list of only the clients who are currently assigned to cases

lstCases shows a filterable list of cases

In txtCaseFilter I have VBA for the onChange event to requery lstCases and the following criteria in the Row Source for lstCases, and on cboClients I have VBA on the AfterUpdate event for the same.

LIKE "*" & [FORMS]![frmCaseSearch]![txtCaseFilter].[Text] & "*"

This part is working fine.

Considering that a person might want to search for a case that hasn't had clients assigned yet, want to build the query for the lstCases in a way that will ignore the cboClient if it's empty, but filter out just the case(s) for a client when one is selected.

I tried this: Nz([Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients],[ClientID]) which works fine if I'm only looking for cases that have a client assigned, but fails to bring in any cases without clients.

Here's the SQL for what I have so far.

```
SELECT tblCases.CaseNumber, tblCasesClients.ClientID
FROM tblCases LEFT JOIN tblCasesClients ON (tblCases.AgencyID = tblCasesClients.AgencyID) AND (tblCases.CaseNumber = tblCasesClients.CaseNumber)
WHERE (((tblCases.CaseNumber) Like "*" & [FORMS]![frmCaseSearch]![txtCaseFilter].[Text] & "*") AND ((tblCasesClients.ClientID)=Nz([Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients],[ClientID])))
ORDER BY tblCases.CaseNumber;
```

How do I write this query so that it ignores the cboClients if it's null, but use it if it's not? The only other option I considered was to write a VBA function to return the Row Source string, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider dynamically building your query with VBA:

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblCases.CaseNumber, tblCasesClients.ClientID" 
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM tblCases"
strSQL = strSQL & " LEFT JOIN tblCasesClients ON (tblCases.AgencyID = tblCasesClients.AgencyID)"
strSQL = strSQL & " AND (tblCases.CaseNumber = tblCasesClients.CaseNumber)"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((tblCases.CaseNumber) Like '*" & [Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![txtCaseFilter] & "*')" 

If Not IsNull([Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients]) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND ((tblCasesClients.ClientID)=([Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients])))"
Else 
    strSQL = strSQL & ")"
End If

strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY tblCases.CaseNumber;"

Forms!frmCaseSearch!lstCases.RowSource = strSQL
```

Comment: My code doesn't look exactly like yours, but this is the type of solution I ended up using. Through all my looking, I couldn't find a way to have the SQL evaluate that condition, so I did almost the same thing that you listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT tblCases.CaseNumber, 
    tblCasesClients.ClientID
FROM tblCases 
LEFT JOIN tblCasesClients 
ON (tblCases.AgencyID = tblCasesClients.AgencyID) 
    AND (tblCases.CaseNumber = tblCasesClients.CaseNumber)
WHERE 
    tblCases.CaseNumber Like "*" & [FORMS]![frmCaseSearch]![txtCaseFilter].[Text] & "*"
    AND (tblCasesClients.ClientID = [Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients])
        or nz([Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients].[Text],"")="")
ORDER BY tblCases.CaseNumber;
```

Comment: I wish that worked. With that code, here's the result I get: When I type in a portion of a case number, it filters those out just fine. If I select a client, it does nothing. I tossed a Debug.Print Me.cboClients in the AfterUpdate event to make sure it was properly triggering, and it seems to be. So, as much as it looks like that should work, it's really not filtering out any of the client IDs. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Try changing the line that starts with OR to:OR tblCasesClients.ClientID=[Forms]![frmCaseSearch]![cboClients].[Text])

Comment: Sorry I went to fast... the code was checking if the field was null and should have been checking if the parameter is null.  I edited the post.  Does this work now?